# IF word in A1 matches word in Col C AND word in B1 matches word in Col E AND

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, worksheet-function

Cell A1 contains a paragraph made of Hebrew words (They are Bible verses in Hebrew, so sometimes more than 254 characters long in each cell).

Cell B1 contains a paragraph of English words (They are Bible verses in English, so sometimes more than 254 characters long in each cell).

Column C contains a list of single Hebrew words.

Column D contains the unique code for each of those Hebrew words.

Column E contains a list of single English words.

Column F contains the unique code for each of those English words.

Finally, Column G contains a list of single words that will be replacing the English words with IF all criteria is met.
(these words are transliterated single words and also some phrases).

So, this is what I'm trying to do:
IF a Hebrew word within the paragraph of cell A1, is the same as a Hebrew word found in the list in Column C,

AND an English word within the paragraph of cell B1, is the same as an English word found in the list in Column E,

AND the unique code for this word is the same in (both) Column D and Column F,

THEN create a new paragraph (Bible verse) in a (new) Column H, which will be a combination: Rendering the existing English words from B1 that did not meet this criteria, but rendering the transliterated words from Column G when all criteria is met.
I'm not sure Excel will support this task because of the 254 character issue, but since I don't know VBA, I figure getting help in Excel will be easier.

Comment: Please [edit] this to ask a specific question.

Comment: Hi Tog and CharlieRB , I have put it all together in an Excel file but I don't see a way to upload it on here. Is there a way to at least post an image so you can see it?

Comment: wow, pretty quick to judge... what have you tried... edit you post... but slow to help at all!

Comment: never mind, There are nice people out there too!

Comment: You can upload your excel file to a file sharing service such as http://www.speedyshare.com/, and then share the download link here.